# Jquery fancytree. How to iterate over all siblings and get custom attributes of each?

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I use sorting plugin. When I move element1 to some other element2, I need to iterate over all siblings of element2. How can I do that?
Moreover, I need to get some custom data- attribute for each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (untested) should do the trick:

```
node.getParent().visit(function(n){
    // Access n.data.myAttr ...
});
```

or simply iterate over the `node.getParent().children` array.

Comment: Every visible node has a parent, since there is always the invisible system root.